# Why does our voice change when we get affected by cold or cough?

Tags: human-biology, pathology

Why does our voice change when we get affected by cold or cough? I observed the voice change thing in so many people including me.

Comment: What has the picture of the virus got to do with your question?

Comment: You observed a virus?

Comment: If I didn't upload the pic, then I can't able to post my question, because of "this question does meet quality standard" red color box. But I posted relevant pic to my question.

Comment: The picture is irrelevant, and once again (this must be the 5th time I've told you specifically) stop using block quotations - learn how to use this site properly!

Comment: When we get affected by cold or cough, the virus infects in the upper respiratory tract and prevents you from making smooth vocal sounds.

Comment: Your vocal cords may be covered with mucus or affected by swollen surrounding tissue during infections of the upper respiratory system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important point is that your voice is influenced by airflow, and your vocal cords. When we're sick, and it depends on what it is, a number of factors change the sound of your voice by influencing the two of these, either: By changing airflow due to respiratory tract swelling or fluid buildup, or by damage/swelling/alterations to the vocal cords. In a couple  of examples: A weak airflow might produce a higher pitch or weaker voice, or perhaps swollen vocal cords produce that hoarseness associated with decreased frequency of vibration.